# Setting up Windows 7 for LAMP development

Tags: windows-7, development-environment, lamp

I'm a .Net guy who has just been handed a LAMP-based project (where P=PHP), without a 'no' option. I am going to have to build this on a Windows 7(64) machine, but it is targeted for a pure LAMP platform.

I am not too worried about PHP or mySQL, I have enough to get by but Linux and Apache may as well be NASA's Curiosity platform.

In the production environment I am going to rely mostly on the Host to configure L and A with the hope that I can pretty much synch up my M and P files, figure out how to do a little app-specific config and go. Perhaps optimistic but I'll start there ;-)

For now the questions are

- what is the most trouble-free way to set up LAMP development on a W7 machine with a view to a relatively trouble-free move to production?
- any reasonable way to do it without giving up my Visual Studio security blanket?
- any suggestions for a walk-through somewhere online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> •what is the most trouble-free way to set up LAMP development on a W7
>   machine with a view to a relatively trouble-free move to production?

Both of these are able to provide you the windows7 LAMP and LAMPP(php/perl) environment.

```
    http://www.ampps.com/
or
    http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
```

Both are simple to use and should make your migration of code over to prod simple.

Comment: What do these do, and which pieces of the question do they answer?

Comment: Thanks for the links, if I have to do this again ampps.org looks promising. Being short on time, brain cycles and answers (posted in august), we charged ahead with a VS2010 PHP-edit plugin and separately installed mysql and php for IIS. Config changes for the production Apache were fairly easy with some help from the host, so far it appears my apprehension may have been misplaced. Maybe we'll discover differently the hard way, but so far so good!

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you install a free Virtual Machine and setup a real LAMP environment, You can access the VM from your windows environment.

If you create a samba bridge(fairly straight forward) , you can develop at your windows environment and deploy to linux easily.

Really easy to setup LAMP environment with VM and pretty sure, you ll find many tutorials, which help you go though the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have to admit bias here, having been mauled by various VMs on various platforms over the years, such that I have avoided diving in again for much longer than is rational. See my comment below for the current solution, but you have motivated me to spend some spare hours de-biasing. Thanks!

Comment: @Serexx ok I understand, why dont you use VMWare. It is very easy to use. Stable. and installing linux is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Wamp server will work perfectly for you: [Wamp Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en)