# How to download, use and keep updated PHP, Apache, MySQL on a machine running on Windows 10 Home operating system?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, wamp

I'm a PHP developer by profession. Till now I was working on **Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS 64-bit** operating system and **LAMP stack**.

Yesterday I bought a new **Lenovo** laptop **pre-installed** with **Windows 10 Home Single Language** operating system.

Then to start development using PHP and MySQL I installed **Wampserver (64 bits & PHP 5.6.15 & PHP 7) 3** on my new machine.

After installation I'm facing so many problems in running PHP and PHPMyAdmin without error. Also it's showing me **PHP Version 5.6.16** installed which is actually a old one.

Actually, I want to install the latest stable versions of following softwares before starting my PHP development :

- PHP Version 7.0.6
- Apache httpd 2.4.20
- MySQL Version 5.7.12
- PHPMyAdmin Version 4.6.1

And also whenever any new stable version for any of the above softwares become available I should be able to upgrade the same software to it like I used to do on my Ubuntu machine by running regular system update.

Can someone please suggest me a way to achieve it without any hassle and trouble? So that I can concentrate more on web development rather than doing configuration settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason not to run Ubuntu inside VirtualBox (or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY ADDONS available for WAMPServer 3

They are all on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/?source=top3_dlp_t5)

Or they can be downloaded from [links on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Or the [alternate download site](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) (often a few days ahead of SourceForge)

Remember that with WAMPServer you can switch between any installed version of Apache/PHP/MYSQL with a simple click of a menu item.

The **latest version of WAMPServer is currently V3.0.4** and comes with

```
Apache2.4.18
MYSQL5.7.11
PHP7.6.19 & 7.0.4
```

> ADDON for PHP7.0.6 is also there ready for download and install
>
> ADDON for Apache2.4.20 is also there ready for download and install
>
> ADDON for MYSQL5.7.12 is also there ready for download and install
>
> ADDON for PHPMyAdmin Version 4.6.1 is also there ready for download and install
>
> There have been a few odd hiccups with phpMyAdmin lately so there is also an ADDON for a tool called `Adminer4.2.4` available also
>
> MYSQL Workbench is also a great tool for messing with MYSQL, but if you install that be careful to only install the Workbench and not another MYSQL Server as well.

What more could you possibly want

Answer (score -1):

Try XAMPP , pick the version you want

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. Just download and start the installer. It's that easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but would I be able to upgrade to the newly released stable versions of any of these softwares easily like I used to do by means of simple System Update in Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873013/setting-up-windows-7-for-lamp-development   - that may help you .